# Copying/Diffing unversioned SVN files via Bash

Tags: svn, bash

First off, my knowledge of bash usage and syntax is very limited. Everything I've done so far as been 'hacked' together so if you see something dumb please let me know :)

I'm trying to write a nightly 'backup' script that will throw the results of `svn diff` into a separate folder. My problem is that the command ignores unversioned files. I'd like the diffs to include those files OR the entire file itself.

Aside: Eclipse(pdt) accomplishes this if you right-click in the Explorer window and select `Team -> Create Patch`. This might be a feature of Subclipse.

I've searched high a low for some way to force this output out of `svn diff` but I'm pretty sure it's not possible.

Here's what I have so far (goal is to copy all unversioned files to my backups folder with the current date):

```
svn status | grep ^? | awk '{print $2}'
File1.php
File2.php
File3.php
```

This outputs a list of files with paths relative to where `svn status` was invoked. I tried piping `cp` to the end but ran into issues with the naming.

**TLDR**: I'd LIKE to append all unversioned files to the result of `svn diff > backups/project.diff` so it includes versioned and unversioned changes.

Alternatively, how can I copy all unversioned files to a specific location (as I was attempting to do in the example above)?

Version infos: Ubuntu 11.04, svn 1.6.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, it seems like you want [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs).   You could copy:

```
svn status | grep ^? | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -J % cp % backups/
```

Or do the append using `cat`:

```
svn status | grep ^? | awk '{print $2}' | xargs cat >> backups/project.diff
```

Be careful of spaces in filenames.

Comment: I believe we're on the same page. Can you explain the xargs portion (or point me in the direction)? I couldn't find anything on the `-J` option or the `%` symbols in man pages. The `cat` solution is close, but can it be written in 'diff' syntax?

Comment: @Mike B, to get the `diff` syntax, you could try diffing against `/dev/null` - you could do that with `xargs` as well.  As far as `xargs` itself goes, I think the man page I linked explains it pretty well.  Normally `xargs` takes the standard input and uses it as command line arguments for the specified utility.  I'm using `-J %` there to put those arguments *before* the destination directory.  That option means "next time you see a `%`, put the standard input there".  The default is to just stick it at the end of the command line.  I'll try a `diff` syntax version and edit it into my answer.